# Multiple Conditions and Object Creation using Design Pattern

Tags: python, design-patterns

I am studying design pattern which I can implement to achieve the same purpose as below. However, I am stuck since most of the examples in the net are pretty simple.

I have tried to look at factory method or even strategy method but can't figure out if any of them could be used.

Any suggestion from the guru here?

```py
def checkSomething():
   if ...:
      return True
   else:
      return False

def main(mode, state):
   if checkSomething() == False:
      if mode == False or (mode == True and state == False):
         obj_a = Class_A()
         return obj_a
      else:
         Class_B().run()
         obj_c = Class_C()
         return obj_c
```

Comment: How can you return either a boolean value or an object in the same function?

Comment: Sorry, I can just return obj_a instead. Not necessary must be False.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can return a pair or tuple where first part may be some enum indicating type.
2. You can create a base class and derive your return class type from common base class. Here, you need to design your program to depend on base class rather than on derived type.

Answer (score 0):

all my personally thoughts

factory pattern opted out here: you are not only creating objects but also making them do stuff

state machine opted out here: there is no state transition here

So I am using the strategy pattern below. But I think you can still use the factory pattern on top so that you further separate the concern of the creation of objects out from the strategy classes.

sort of C# pseudo code here:

```
interface IClass
{
    void Run();
}

class Class_A : IClass { ... }
class Class_B : IClass { ... }
class Class_C : IClass { ... }

interface IStrategy
{
    IClass Execute();
}

class StrategyA : IStrategy
{
    IClass IStrategy.Execute()
    {
        var obj_a = Class_A();
        return obj_a;
    }
}

class StrategyB : IStrategy
{
    IClass IStrategy.Execute()
    {
        Class_B.Run();
        var obj_c = Class_C();
        return obj_c;
    }
}


class DecisionMaker
{
    private IStrategy _strategy;

    public DecideStrategy(IStrategy strategy) => _strategy = strategy;

    public IClass ExecuteStrategy() => _strategy.Execute();
}

main()
{
    var decisionMaker = new decisionMaker();
    if conditionA
        decisionMaker.DecideStrategy(new StrategyA());
    else if conditionB
        decisionMaker.DecideStrategy(new StrategyB());

    return decisionMaker.ExecuteStrategy();
}
```